# google adsense not displaying in blog

Tags: javascript, blogger, adsense

i have created blog http://toptenbestthings.blogspot.in/  and sign up for adsense every thing is completed verified all done and got my code to paste website / blog

### Adsense code (Asynchronized) method

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- toptenbestthings_sidebar-right-1_AdSense4_250x250_as -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:250px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2471429062443535"
     data-ad-slot="1380963202"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

and placed code in html method

and even added adsense to display ads using layout method

**but ads not displaying**
even in layout method not displaying

this how i added code to my blog and page
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/181957?topic=28897

**Can some one please help me trying to solve this for past 11 days**

And i need to check my account is verified is this the reason ads are not shown are any problem

Comment: Did you just get the adsense approval? Coz it takes some time before the ads appear!

Comment: There’s an error message in Chrome console, saying `document.write` can not be used from within scripts that are added dynamically …

Comment: @GargAnkit yes approved .. how can i check apporved or not

Comment: @CBroe so how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your script in order to show ads on blog.

detele `ca-pub-`after ad-client

detele `data-at-stot="????????"`

after that, go to blogger and add modified javascript code in HTML/Javascript gadget of Blogger and manage its position accordingly. It will show ads now.

You can watch my video about this [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp-_TejaFvc)